# MYSQL grouping with condition

Tags: mysql

i need help for grouping mysql data.
here is my table

```
|Team  | Type | Value |
|------|------|-------|
|  A   |  0   | 10    |
|  A   |  1   | 5     |
|  B   |  0   | 10    |
|  B   |  0   | 10    |
|  A   |  1   | 20    |
|  B   |  1   | 20    |
-----------------------
```

I would like to group it to by 'Team' but grouping must only group with same type and sum the values, Expected result:

```
|Team  | Type | Value |
|------|------|-------|
|  A   |  0   | 10    |
|  A   |  1   | 25    |
|  B   |  0   | 20    |
|  B   |  1   | 20    |
-----------------------
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    SELECT Team,
           Type,
           SUM(Value)
      FROM table
  GROUP BY Team, Type;
```

Something like that should work, as you are able to group by multiple fields in MySQL.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need this

```
(root@localhost) [test]> select team, type, sum(value) from a group by team, type
    -> ;
+------+------+------------+
| team | type | sum(value) |
+------+------+------------+
| A    | 0    |         10 |
| A    | 1    |         25 |
| B    | 0    |         20 |
| B    | 1    |         20 |
+------+------+------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

can see the page http://www.w3school.com.cn/sql/sql_groupby.asp